# Href in \subtitle

Tags: titles

How can i put `href` at the page subtitle? I have a:

```
\usepackage[%
  verbose,
  colorlinks=true,
  naturalnames=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

%
% Title page
%
\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\setkomafont{subtitle}{\normalfont\Large}
\href{http://www.wikibooks.org}{Wikibooks home}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

But i'm getting link at the another page. How can i make it correctly?

Thank you.

Comment: The `href` has to be inside the Subtitle? Or am i missing something?

Comment: The best way would to have text subtitle and href under it

Comment: `\subtitle{Subtitle \\
\href{http://www.wikibooks.org}{Wikibooks home}}`

Comment: @0xAX Please, make your code more informative by adding the class you're using: the standard classes don't provide the `\subtitle` command, so either you're using a different class than `article` or have defined a `\subtitle` command yourself. You should see that the information is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

`\subtitle` is provided by the KOMA-classes. 
You can place nearly everything in most of the fields predefined
by KOMA, even a picture if you want.  The important thing to note
is, that everything that shall be printed on a titlepage has to
be in one of those fields. 
Please note that placing stuff on a new line by using `\\` will
not work in any field. It works for `\author`, `\title` and other
as they are typeset within a `center` environment.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle \\[1em]
    \href{http://www.ctan.org}{\includegraphics[width=2em]{example-image-1x1}}}
\setkomafont{subtitle}{\normalfont\Large}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

If you want to know more about constructiong an own titlepage, please refer to [How to construct my own titlepage?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280/37907)

Comment: @0xAX: `koma-script`, good though it is, is not “standard” — if you don’t say which class you are using, people here will assume `article` ... which is why the rule is *always* to provide a _complete_ sample, including `\documentclass`

Comment: @wasteofspace Isn't the current MWE enough? Suggestions for improving the post?